# Image height to adjust to screen height

Tags: html, css, image, height, screen

So I have an image background, and I want it to fill the height of the screen depending on the screen size, laptop, ipad, phone, etc.

I want the height to adjust to the screen height.

```
.mobile-cover {
    background: url(http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Modern-wallpaper-10.jpg) center top;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    border: red 0px solid;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
    height: 600px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tz2erwch/

Comment: background-size: cover; try this. it will help you

Comment: Thanks for the help man, didn't help with my particular problem though! Solved it now :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nevermind! I've answered my own question!

For anyone else who is interested I simply used

> height: 100vh;

where one 1vh is equal to 1% of the viewport's height.

I changed to 80vh as 20% of the screen is taken by nav. This worked well.

Comment: Or use `height: 100%;`

Comment: `height: 100vh` = 100% of the viewport height.

`height: 100%` = 100% of the parent's element height.

They are slightly different...

Comment: It's only example, we can use 80% or anyone else. But remember that **html, body** tag must have `width: 100%; height: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```